# What purpose does third-person verb conjugation serve or used to serve?

Tags: history, conjugation, inflectional-morphology

There is one thing in English that doesn't make sense to me: adding 's' (or 'es') to verbs when the subject is a third person. It seems redundant and adds no extra information to the sentence.

"I like cakes", but "he likes cakes" --> 's' serves no purpose here.
In other European languages, there are conjugations for other subjects as well, e.g. in Dutch: "ik spreek", "jij spreekt", "jullie spreken". All of those conjugations are, in my opinion, purposeless in modern languages.

But as a product of linguistic evolution, they must have been there to serve a purpose. That purpose is lost now but I'm very interested in finding out what it was.

Comment: @XavierHernándezBalcázar: Old English did have pronouns for third person: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=he&searchmode=none

Comment: They are indeed remnants of a fuller system where every person had a unique (or more or less unique) form, just like they still do in, say, Spanish. Germanic languages developed a heavy initial stress, which resulted in a lot of final syllables (and the distinctions those syllables made) being lost; personal pronouns started being mandatory in compensation. This didn't happen in Spanish: _tomo_ ‘I take’, _tomaremos_ ‘we will take’, _tomasteis_ ‘ye took’, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing from your name that you're Japanese, in which case, I might ask: what's the point of different stems that serve no real function in Japanese—why not just say 持ちない instead of 持たない?

Comment: It encodes that the mood is *indicative.*

Comment: Only *one* thing? ;) There are *loads* of things in English which make no logical sense to me, and I'm a native speaker. One can sometimes find out how they arose, but that doesn't mean they they arose for a logical reason.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks for your answer. About the Japanese stem, even though I have no expertise in Japanese, I do have a theory that might answer your question. However this is not a place to discuss your question. I can only say: Japanese's verb conjugation is not entirely senseless even in its modern usage.

Comment: @CarSmack Would you mind elaborate or give me some reference for further reading about how conjugation relates to indicative mood?

Comment: Early languages had lots of redundancies, such as all the declensions in Latin. Some of these have faded away as languages evolved, but many are still with us. Discussion of why they existed in the first place would be more appopriate on a linguistics site than here.

Comment: @Barmar This is the definition of this site: "English Language & Usage: For linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."

Comment: @FukuzawaYukio Then what is linguistics.stackexchange.com for?

Comment: @Barmar I believe it is for general linguistic interest. My question is specific for English.

Comment: You might as well ask why we have any verb conjugation at all. It's just a remnant from earlier languages that English evolved from.

Comment: I support your question Fukuzawa Yukio. Historically, there must have been some reason; perhaps it's a borrowed feature, perhaps it made agency clear when a subject was left out, I'm really not sure. But even if the reason is not immediately apparent, it doesn't mean there's no reason. It's worthy of exploration, or, if it resists simple answers, at least evidence-based speculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19305/discussion-between-rusty-tuba-and-tchrist).

Comment: @Barmar That comment reads like it just means: "I don't know the answer, so I'm not interested"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many features in language, there is no clear answer for "what purpose does that serve". Many European languages retain distinct endings for most or all the combinations of person and number; the modern Scandinavian languages have lost all of them. English has lost most, but retains the 3s ending.

Languages with full verbal conjugation *may* allow speakers to omit personal pronouns; but do not necessarily do so.

Really this is a historical accident, and there is not necessarily any reason or justification for it.